# Take a Consumer Offline (Planned Outage) with MassTransit

Tags: masstransit

I have a number of servers, each running a single instance of a service/ that listens to the same queue/endpoint which (intentionally!) results in a [Competing Consumer](http://docs.masstransit-project.com/en/latest/overview/underthehood.html?highlight=competing) pattern.

This solution is great as it provides both load-balancing and high-availability and is perfect for my use case.

What I would like to be able to achieve, however, is a way to be able to take individual nodes offline *without any impact*. In other words, a way to be able to tell a node to finish the processing of any messages that it has already received, but to not consume any *new* messages (rather than just switching the service off and having to manage the termination of any in-flight processing of messages).

Are there any recommendations for how I could solve this? One advantage of being able to do this would be to allow for non-disruptive rolling upgrades/deployments.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `busControl.Stop();` should cleanly shutdown the bus, including a graceful shutdown of each receive endpoint. This would allow current consumers to complete, but prevents new consumers from picking up messages.

Once the `Stop` method returns, the process may exit and the remaining nodes will stay online.